# Ruby / Rails web applications to learn from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering. Can you recommend me some existing "open source" web applications that **I can learn from**. Web applications that use BDD, RSpec, etc "The right way" and are good to learn from.

Thanks for your comments and have a nice day!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find good examples of Rails applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193632/where-can-i-find-good-examples-of-rails-applications)